# Python optional group in regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have the following regular expression in Python:

```
m = re.match(r'(?P<name>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?P<limit>_\d+K)(?P<code>_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?(_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?(_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?(_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?(_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?.(?P<file_format>\w+)?',
                    file_name, re.M | re.I)
```

It is used to validate a file name against a specific pattern and I also take the values of the groups from the file name like so:

name = m.group('name')

This works fine if the file name is exactly in the given format like so:

file_name = "name_122K_someCode_someotherthing.jpg"

However in some cases the  or  parts may be missing from the file name. In those cases, obviously, the file name won't match the regexp and I won't be able to get the rest of the values from it.

How can I make the  and  optional groups so the pattern matches even if any of those or both miss from the file name?

Comment: You could make all the parts optional, and assert that there is at least a non whitspace char followed by a dot and 1+ word chars at the end. `^(?=\S+\.\w+$)(?P<name>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?(?P<limit>_\d+K)?(?P<code>_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?(_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?(_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?(_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?(_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?\.(?P<file_format>\w+)?$`  https://regex101.com/r/AUGLGj/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If some of the parts can be missing, you could make all the groups optional except the file format if that should be present.

As there are no spaces matched, you could prepend the pattern with a positive lookahead `^(?=\S+\.\w+$)` to assert at least a single non whitespace char bofore matching the `file_format` group.

Note to escape the dot `\.` to match it literally

```
^(?=\S+\.\w+$)(?P<name>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?(?P<limit>_\d+K)?(?P<code>_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?(_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?(_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?(_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?(_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?\.(?P<file_format>\w+)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ed8xrJ/1)

If all the parts can be optional, you could assert a word character and make the whole part at the end of the string optional, including the dot.

```
^(?=\w)(?P<name>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?(?P<limit>_\d+K)?(?P<code>_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?(_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?(_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?(_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?(_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?(?:\.(?P<file_format>\w+))?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1lGL4R/1)

**Edit** As suggested by [@JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv) you could shorten the pattern a bit by using a quantifier to capture all the values of the optional capturing groups into a single group:

```
^(?=\w)(?P<name>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?(?P<limit>_\d+K)?(?P<code>_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?((?:_[a-zA-Z0-9]+){0,4})(?:\.(?P<file_format>\w+))?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q0HLX1/1)

Comment: @cycero I have added an update. 1 pattern with the file extension, and another without it.

Comment: @JvdV Nope, I think you are right. That is the sin of copy pasting :-)

Comment: @JvdV I would make it like this `^(?=\w)(?P<name>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?(?P<limit>_\d+K)?(?P<code>_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?((?:_[a-zA-Z0-9]+){0,4})(?:\.(?P<file_format>\w+))?$` Because when using `(_[a-zA-Z0-9]+){0,4}` you are repeating a capturing group, which will give you the value of the last iteration. See https://regex101.com/r/Jfgfnf/1

Comment: @JvdV `[^\W_]` is a shorter way, but in Python can could possibly also match this https://ideone.com/rqrCyF I think it is ok for the current matches though.